# Constructing images using Zen Cart

Tags: zen-cart

I installed zen-cart on my website. But when i insert the image in admin panel, i found the image link broken. Need Help. [image]

My code

```
<?php define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http:/'); 
define('HTTP_CATALOG_SERVER', 'http://****'); 
define('HTTPS_CATALOG_SERVER', 'https://**'); 
define('ENABLE_SSL_CATALOG', 'true'); 
define('DIR_WS_CATALOG', '/'); 
define('DIR_WS_HTTPS_CATALOG', '/'); 
define('DIR_FS_CATALOG', '/home/**/public_html/'); 
define('DB_TYPE', 'mysql'); 
define('DB_PREFIX', '');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'); 
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', ); 
define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', ); 
define('DB_DATABASE', ); 
define('SQL_CACHE_METHOD', 'none');
```

Comment: <?php

define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http:/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG_SERVER', 'http://****');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG_SERVER', 'https://**');
define('ENABLE_SSL_CATALOG', 'true');
define('DIR_WS_CATALOG', '/');
define('DIR_WS_HTTPS_CATALOG', '/');
define('DIR_FS_CATALOG', '/home/**/public_html/');

define('DB_TYPE', 'mysql'); 
define('DB_PREFIX', '');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', );
define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', );
define('DB_DATABASE', );
define('SQL_CACHE_METHOD', 'none');

Answer (score 0):

Check `DIR_WS_IMAGES` and `DIR_WS_UPLOADS` in `includes/configure.php` and  and `DIR_WS_CATALOG_IMAGES` in `admin/includes/configure.php`. You want these values to be consistent.  Also check in `admin/includes/configure.php` the value `DIR_FS_CATALOG_IMAGES`.